# Why is my SQL Server database file so large?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, database-size

I have a relatively simple database that is over 300MB on disk.  When I look at the table data it adds up to just over 5MB.  Please see the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

<sub>This screenshot can also be seen [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/ANEHNJwuJPOl).</sub>

If I add several more devices, I will run out of disk space at this rate! Why is this so large and how do I shrink it and keep it under control automatically?

Query results from the "answer" in [this related thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175649/sum-of-table-sizes-dont-match-with-mdf-size) say that reserved MB should be 7.66, which is still far more reasonable than 300+.

---

It is the log file.  I've backed it up, told it to truncate, shrunk the log file and still no luck. I've tried shrinking both database and the log file directly.  I should probably give up and move to simple mode, but I would prefer full recovery if I could control the log size.

Answer (score 3):

Simple recovery doesn't make it easier to shrink a log file. It will just empty the log for you (when checkpoint occurs), same thing as you do when you perform a log backup. The thing with a log file, regarding shrink, is that it cannot be shrunk beyond the last used Virtual Log File (VLF). So, examine the VLF layout if you are interested. If just do a log backup and then shrink *several times* and the last VLF will eventually move towards beginning of the file and the shrink will happen. More info: https://karaszi.com/large-transaction-log-file

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check recovery model of database. Log will not truncate untill log back initiate. 
Also check used and free space either by query or navigate to database - shrink- properties and see how much space is acquired by log/mdf file